# How does JIRA know what an unresolved issue is?

Tags: jira

I am using a custom workflow designed in JIRA with custom transitions and custom issue statuses.

How does JIRA know what an unresolved issue is so that it displays the statistics for a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An issue is unresolved if the system Resolution field contains no value. It is resolved if the Resolution field contains any value.

More info at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOCSPRINT/Resolved,+Resolution+and+Resolution+Date